# URL within angled brackets is disappearing from post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

I was trying to use angled brackets to create a link inside my post, but it is disappearing from the post when rendered.

For example, the following:

```
This is Sparta! <example.org>
```

produces:

> This is Sparta!

I am not simply removing `<example.org>` from the blockquotes, as it is visible in the raw text. Like normal, escaping breaks this, so it is a Markdown issue.

I am on a MacBook Pro mid-2012 (shouldn't be important) and developer beta 1 of macOS Sierra. I've used the following web browsers and reproduced this issue successfully:

- Chromium Version 54.0.2792.0 (64-bit)
- Safari Version 10.0 (12602.1.32.7)
- Google Chrome Canary Version 54.0.2791.0 (64-bit)
- Google Chrome Canary Version 54.0.2792.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the syntax correctly, as you didn't provide an actual URL to the parser (you cannot just enter example.org" - you need to enter a **full URL** including the protocol at the front). Therefore, it does not get rendered as a link, and the parser ultimately removed the entire thing as invalid HTML because it is not on the allowed list of HTML elements.

This is what you should use:

```
This is Sparta! <http://example.org>
```

Which produces this:

> This is Sparta! http://example.org

Also of note, characters before or after it do not actually have any effect whatsoever:

> Hhttp://example.org Ihttp://example.org !http://example.org